# Fill a partially filled table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to fill a partially filled table in mysql, I don't know if it possible though, I couldn't find a way to do it without losing data.

Since it's always easier to explain with an example. I have something like this:

```
+-------+-------+----------+
| Names | total | elements |
+-------+-------+----------+
| data1 |     2 | elem1    |
|       |       | elem2    |
| data2 |     3 | elem3    |
|       |       | elem4    |
|       |       | elem5    |
+-------+-------+----------+
```

And I'm trying to get something like this :

```
+-------+----------+
| Names | elements |
+-------+----------+
| data1 | elem1    |
| data1 | elem2    |
| data2 | elem3    |
| data2 | elem4    |
| data2 | elem5    |
+-------+----------+
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to do this nicely with just a basic query, but this is the sort of thing procedure logic can be used for.

Check out the docs on WHILE loops. What you'll want to do is loop through that table ordered by the elements column. If the Names column is set, set a variable to the value of names, and if names is empty, set the column to that variable.

The example here should get you started:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html

Comment: So I tried to do as you said, but I get a syntax error >.<  

 [Here's the code](http://pastebin.com/jG6DshwD)  

 Thank you very much for your help ! :)